# Is it possible to execute document.forms[0].submit() in JMeter?

Tags: javascript, jmeter

I am testing the login in our page, it seems to be working fine, however after a successful POST, the server will respond with

```
<body>
    <form method="POST" name="hiddenform" action="someAction"><input type="hidden" name="wa" value="wsignin1.0" />
        <input type="hidden" name="wresult" value="someValue/>
        <input type="hidden" name="wctx" value="rm=0&amp;id=passive&amp;ru=%2f" />
        <noscript>
            <p>Script is disabled. Click Submit to continue.</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </noscript>
    </form>
    <script language="javascript">
    window.setTimeout('document.forms[0].submit()', 0);
    </script>
</body>
```

So in a browser, javascript will automatically send the form, however Jmeter does not do this automatically. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you,
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Submitting a [Form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp) is basically sending the associated [HTTP Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods), normally a [POST](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) one, the relevant configuration of the [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler would be

[image]

Check out [Fill Forms and Submit With JMeter - Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/fill-forms-and-submit-with-jmeter-made-easy/) article for more information.

However instead of building your request manually it makes more sense to just record it using your favorite browser and JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

You might also need to perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of these `wresult` and `wctx` parameters and extract the values from the previous response using i.e. [CSS Selector Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS_Selector_Extractor) in case if they're dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's the way: [WebDriver Sampler](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins-webdriver) that would simulate the browser behavior.

HTTP Sampler just go for very basic HTML parsing to retrieve the resources, but it doesn't execute everything browser does.

Check out these two articles on the subject: 
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler/
and 
https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered/